# Not able to generate Random images some times in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, random, int

I'm trying to generate random images several times from an array in an android app.

but Those images are generated one time  that are skip and try to store remaining images in new array and 
select again a new random image. But some time my app crashes due to "IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0"
So how to fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
  all = new int[]{R.id.img3_1, R.id.img3_2, R.id.img3_3, R.id.img3_4,R.id.img3_5, R.id.img3_6, R.id.img3_7, R.id.img3_8,
                R.id.img3_9,R.id.img3_10,R.id.img3_11,R.id.img3_12,R.id.img3_13,R.id.img3_14,R.id.img3_15,R.id.img3_16};

        id = all[random.nextInt(all.length)];
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(findViewById(id), "backgroundResource", R.drawable.new_stateimg, R.drawable.org_state).setDuration(2000);
        animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        animator.start();


        final int index = Ints.indexOf(all, id);
        all2 = Arrays.copyOf(all, index);
        id1 = all2[random.nextInt(all2.length)];

        ObjectAnimator animator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(findViewById(id1), "backgroundResource", R.drawable.new_stateimg, R.drawable.org_state).setDuration(2000);
        animator1.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        animator1.start();


        final int index1 = Ints.indexOf(all2, id1);
        int[] all3 = Arrays.copyOf(all2, index1);
        id2 = all3[random.nextInt(all3.length)];//line 271


        ObjectAnimator animator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(findViewById(id2), "backgroundResource", R.drawable.new_stateimg, R.drawable.org_state).setDuration(2000);
        animator2.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        animator2.start();
```

my Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: brainreadersystem.com.ncss, PID: 7474
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
    at brainreadersystem.com.ncss.Game.linear16(Game.java:271)
    at brainreadersystem.com.ncss.Game.check(Game.java:236)
    at brainreadersystem.com.ncss.Game.access$000(Game.java:20)
    at brainreadersystem.com.ncss.Game$4.onClick(Game.java:184)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**Update:**
scenario of above code:

For example I have a image view like 3*3=9 and I want to change the color of some images (3 of 9 image). but now some time it colors only one due to above code(after using slipperyseal's answer).

Answer (score 0):

`random.nextInt()` is being called with a value of zero. It can't find a random number between 0 and 0, thus the Exception.

It looks like this happens when the first `random.nextInt()` call with length of `all.length` happens to return returns zero.

```
    id = all[random.nextInt(all.length)];   // element at index zero
```

This sets up the condition for the length of the all2 to be zero, as id at index 0.

```
    final int index = Ints.indexOf(all, id);   // index zero
    all2 = Arrays.copyOf(all, index);          // zero length array
    id1 = all2[random.nextInt(all2.length)];   // kaboom!
```

I won't offer a fix because i don't really understand what your code needs to do. Something like this would stop it exploding, but i'm not sure it's correct for what you are trying to achieve. If the index is 0 force it to 1..

```
    all2 = Arrays.copyOf(all, index == 0 ? 1 : index);
```

(and apply the same to all3)

Comment: your answer fix the app crash issue but now some time it work only single imageview.

Comment: For example I have a image view like 3*3=9 and I want to change the color of some images (3 of 9 image). but now some time it colors only one due to above code.

Comment: As mentioned I don't understand the logic behind the subsequent arrays and how that relates to the expected results

Comment: yes bro,I understand that .so have to any idea to fix this.